# CS50 2019 Vigenere - second loop

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

First I got my code to do the following:

key: ab
Plaintext: Test me
Ciphertext: Tfsu ne

I am ofcourse trying to get my key to skip space, (Tfsu mf), so I tried adding an extra counter (m-counter) for my key, to make sure that it doesn't increment after every iteration over the plaintext. The result, however, is that now I get:

key: ab
Plaintext: Test me
Ciphertext: Uftu nf

So now it acts like my key is bb.

Could somebody explain the 'logic' why this second loop causes this change in output, instead of only incrementing when a character will be ciphered (i.e. is alphabetic)?

```
            for (int m = 0; m<l; m++)
                {
                   for(int e = 0; e<z; e++)
                       {
                          if (islower(plaintext[e]))
                           {                                         
                           ciphertext [e] = (plaintext [e] + shift `(argv[1][m%l]) - 'a') %26 + 'a';`
                            }
                           if (isupper(plaintext[e]))
                            {    

                            ciphertext [e] = (plaintext [e] + shift (argv[1][m%l]) - 'A') %26 + 'A';      
                            }  
                       }
                 }

             for (int q = 0; q<z;q++)
                  {          
                     if (!isalpha(plaintext[q]) )
                          {    
                           ciphertext [q] = (plaintext [q]);
                           } 
                  } 


printf ("ciphertext: ");
for (int i = 0; i<z; i++)   
    { 
    printf ("%c", ciphertext [i]);
    }
 printf("\n");
```

Comment: Please turn the shown code into a [mre]. For that I'd expect less code concerned with getting the data (arguments, input) etc. Please process readily available data in arrays of explicitly initialised arrays. Ideally you can free the code from all cs50 dependencies, which would make reproducing it much easier. Also please get rid of the generous empty lines and fix the indentation.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your advice; I cleaned it up and am only showing the code regarding my problem. I hope I didn't remove too much now?

Comment: Sorry, you did remove too much. Please read the link I provided again. Also please do more work on fixing indentation. Sorry to say, but I am tempted to just write exactly the same comment again.

Comment: Ok, this is new for me so I'm not sure what you mean with fixing the indentation. Could you be more specific, so I know how to do it better next time?

Comment: Bother about indentation last. Read, understand and apply the rest of my first comment first.

Comment: Fine, I will elaborate. Please turn the shown code into a [mre]. For that, read that link. You desccribe that you get an actual result when running the code. This means that you CAN run it. That is NOT possible with the shown code, because it can not even be compiled. So first thing, post MORE code, enough to make it possible to actually compile the code you show. Then make sure that the code you show can be executed after being built. It must hence be a complete program. The shown code is of course not a complete program because it shows no `main()`.

Comment: At this point you will probably say "That is what I did first!" and that is not entirely wrong. However that first code failed to match the "minimal" of [mre]. It contained a lot of code which is not necessary for demonstrating your problem. It contains e.g. code for reading in the data to process, including to find the data via command line arguments `argc, argv`. All of that is not needed if you just work on data which is already in hard coded arrays with constant initialisaitons. Getting rid of that focuses on your problem. It also prevents any input inconsistencies from getting in the way.

Comment: The link proposes, in case that an existing answer DID actually help you completely, to use the mechanism provided by the system for that purpose, to accept it with the corresponding button. Most of the thing I try to convince you of are described in this last link I will recommend: [tour]. It is really prominently recommended for reading when you create an account at StackOverflow and I can tell that you have not bothered to read it. By that I do not mean that you act like not knowig about. I mean that I can really see that you did not read it completely, from you profile.

Comment: The indentation is just something to make already meaningful code easier to read. Hence I propose to do it, but as the last thing to do for improving your question, totally not worth bothering about if all the other things still puzzle you.

Comment: Thank you, I do appreciate this. I suppose I was too impatient about finally solving this problem, to read up on the tour and so on. The guy below did clarify where I was wrong, and gave me a new perspective, so I now accepted his answer as the solution (I first thought upvoting it was considered as accepting).

Comment: I am happy to have helped you with understanding. Good luck and have fun with your further participation on StackOverflow. You can get my upvote on your question, if you improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop `for (int m = 0; m<l; m++)` tells the program to cipher the entire plain text with key[0], then cipher the entire plaintext with key[1], etc through l. Which exactly describes the result you see (ie looks like it is ciphering with "bb", because it actually is!)

Generally in this assigment, one should not use a loop to control the key index. It should be incremented when used (and of course "wrap around" at the lenght).

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse, it overwrites the ciphering with the first key! Thanks a lot!